# How to use Redis 6 ACL feature in node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, acl

I created a Redis client in node.js using the "node_redis" npm module, which is a popular Redis client for the node, but this module does not support the latest Redis features like ACL (Access Control List). Is there any other library that supports all the features of Redis 6? if not then how to use Redis ACL feature in node apps

Answer (score 1):

```
client['auth'] = null;
client.send_command('AUTH', ['<username>', '<password>'], redis.print);
```

Seen here : [Connecting to managed redis with auth username/password nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432302/connecting-to-managed-redis-with-auth-username-password-nodejs)