# Connecting to managed redis with auth username/password nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, redis, digital-ocean, node-redis

Edit: After thinking about the issue, the real question is what is an example of connecting to digitalocean's managed redis with node-redis using tls?

I'm able to connect just fine with redisinsight GUI client using username / password, but cannot connect with nodejs. It's on the same computer so no firewall issues.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_PORT, process.env.REDIS_URL, {no_ready_check: true});
client.auth('password', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return
    }
    console.log('auth')
});
```

One thing I'm confused about is where to enter the username? It's just 'default' but the documentation for node_redis doesn't provide a way to give a username during auth.

Error is: `AbortError: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed.`

Here's my working lightly anonymized redisinsight connection screen.

How do I do the same in node-redis?

[image]

Comment: Just curious: Could you try this way to create a client `createClient(port, host, {auth_pass: password, tls: {servername: host}})`? Maybe the `tls` option is required.

Comment: @manishg still get the same problem with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AUTH` command, as stated in [the docs](https://redis.io/commands/auth):

> When ACLs are used, the single argument form of the command,
> where only the password is specified, assumes that the implicit username is "default".

So even if you are using Redis 6, where additional users are supported, your authentication for `default` should work.

**The error you're seeing is the result of a broken connection**, e.g. you somehow lost connection with the Redis server. `node-redis` is dealing with one of two scenarios (or both) - the connection has timed out or the the reconnect attempts have exceeded the maximum number specified in a config. I would double check your connection information and how your redis server is configured.

I see you are using TLS, you may find this useful: [Securing Node Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947527/securing-node-redis)

If you want to authenticate node-redis client with a different user, when using Redis 6, you will have to use `send_command`, but before you need to *remove* the current `AUTH` command, as currently node-redis doesn't support the new command `AUTH <username> <password>`.

```
client['auth'] = null;
client.send_command('AUTH', ['<username>', '<password>'], redis.print);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a database as a service https://www.digitalocean.com/products/managed-databases-redis/ so I don't have access to the redis conf. When I see "too many reconnection attempts" I assume this is because the connection failed and it reconnecting too much as a result? What's the correct way to connect with tls in node-redis?

Comment: I think it is probably because of the TLS-enabled you show in the screenshot. I'd say try this Digital Ocean tutorial first: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-managed-redis-over-tls-with-stunnel-and-redis-cli. Once you can connect with redis-cli, try the `{auth_pass: 'password', tls: {servername: 'location.of.server'}}` configuration for node-redis mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947527/securing-node-redis

Comment: Thanks though that doesn't make a difference for me. The answer might be outdated as I don't see auth_pass in any documentation for node-redis. It's just 'password' now.

Comment: Were you able to connect with redis-cli? Once you've done that you can try setting up your node app the same way as redis-cli.

Comment: I'm just going to accept you to thank you for the effort, the answer was specific to my env.